# Parameter in jsf bean is null. why?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a jsf page where i show a datatable. In the p:column tag i want to set the background-Color. The Background-Color will be determined by the Method `public String getTrafficColor(Trgs trgs)` in the TrgsLazyDataActions Bean.

But The Parameter trgs of the Method `getTrgsTrafficColor(Trgs trgs)` is always null and so i get a NullPointerException.

In the p:column-tag i Transfer the tempTrgs Object

```
#{trgsLazyDataActions.getTrafficColor(tempTrgs)}"
```

The tempTrgs is the var of p:datatable and it is not null.

I don't why the transferd paramter is null in the Bean.

```
   <p:column headerText="#{texts['trgs.atp']}"
            filterBy="#{tempTrgs.atp}" width="40" 
            style="background-color: #{trgsLazyDataActions.getTrafficColor(tempTrgs)}">

            ....

    </p:column>
```

.

```
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
@Named
public class TrgsLazyDataActions extends TrgsActionsBase implements Serializable {


//The Parameter trgs is null. I don't know why ?  
public String getTrafficColor(Trgs trgs) {
    Factory auditedFactory = getAuditedTrgs(trgs.getTrgsID()).getFactory();
    if (trgs.getAtp() < auditedFactory.getAtpMin()) {
      return Consts.RED;
    } else if (trgs.getAtp() > auditedFactory.getAtpMax()) {
      return Consts.YELLOW;
    } else {
      return Consts.GREEN;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What p taglib is ?

Comment: We don't see any definition of tempTrgs, where is it defined ?

Comment: [mcve] please!!